# Binary Search Tree error

Tags: c++, tree

I want to find minimum value in a Binary Search Tree.
I have written below code. But when i call the function from main and I pribt the return value, it is printing as 0 always.

cal you please help.

```
int findMinimumValue(struct tnode* node)
{
int min=node->data;
if(node->lchild==NULL)
{
   return min;
}
else
    findMinimumValue(node->lchild);
}
```

Comment: What language is this?  (Please tag the question appropriately.)  Have you attempted to debug this?

Comment: If you turned up your compiler's warning level, you would find the problem immediately.

Comment: I did not get any error while I was running and compiling the code.

Comment: Tree created is fine. i am able to traverse the tree properly. But I dont know why the value is comin out to be 0. Below is the way i have made a call to the function.   cout<<findMinimumValue(root)

Comment: Yes, exactly.  You should set your compiler to use a higher warning level.  (In GCC, you can do `-Wall -Wextra`; in VS you can use `/W3` or `/W4`.)

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you're not actually returning the value of your recursion call:

```
int findMinimumValue(struct tnode* node)
{
    int min=node->data;

    if(node->lchild==NULL)
    {
        return min;
    }
    else
    {
        // you need the return here or you're never returning 
        // anything in this branch
        return findMinimumValue(node->lchild);
    }
}
```

for that matter not really much need for the variable as it is, what about:

```
int findMinimumValue(struct tnode* node)
{
    if (node->lchild == NULL)
        return node->data;
    else
        return findMinimumValue(node->lchild);
}
```

---

oh, and just as a mention: I would consider using the non-recursive version of this instead; it's also pretty simple:

```
int findMinimumValue(struct tnode* node)
{
    while (node->lchild != NULL)
        node = node->lchild;

    return node->data;
}
```

Comment: bleah, getting too late to write answers had to edit twice because somehow I went from thinking "no return in this branch" to typing "min =". in two places.

Comment: Thanks. Now it worked. It was a stupid mistake from my side. I have many problems in recursion. can you please suggest some tutorial link ets to improve the concept.

Comment: :) I've been there, no worries. recursion can be hard. as for a tutorial, a quick google turned this one up, it seemed pretty cool: http://erwnerve.tripod.com/prog/recursion/